# Convergence in probability of ratio to 1 and convergence of a sequence to a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ where is a positive random variable. Now if $X_n/Y_n\xrightarrow{p}1$ do we have that $Y_n\xrightarrow{d}X$? Are the following first steps valid: $P(Y_n<z)\leq P(|X_n-Y_n|>|Y_n|\varepsilon z)+P(X_n<z+\varepsilon)$, then letting n go to infinity would provide the result?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397668/321264

Answer (score 1):

The steps need justification. For example, we have to be sure that $z+\epsilon$ is a continuity point of the cumulative distribution function of $X$. Moreover, it is not completely clear from the assumptions that $P(|X_n-Y_n|>|Y_n|\varepsilon z)\to 0$. However, we can use the following:
$$
Y_n=\left(\frac{Y_n}{X_n}-1\right)X_n+X_n.
$$
From [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542620/proving-slutskys-theorem), we get that $\left(\frac{Y_n}{X_n}-1\right)X_n\to 0$  in probability and from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667695/proof-of-the-first-equation-of-slutskys-theorem), that $Y_n\to X$ in distribution.